# Protractor selenium ChromeDriver Angular4

Tags: angular, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get 'ng e2e' to work, however, I have run into an error.

```
WebDriverError: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
```

I use the protractor, which comes pre-installed with the Angular CLI. I have installed the binary for ChromeDriver again, I also tried using different browsers with different drivers, but I always get the same error. Selenium server is up and running and works fine, the binary for ChromeDriver is just not found. Does anyone know a solution? I use chromedriver_2.33 and Angular 4.

Here is the error:

```
[10:39:39] I/update - chromedriver: chromedriver_2.33 up to date
[10:39:39] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[10:39:39] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[10:39:40] E/launcher - unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506106 (8a06c39c4582fbfbab6966dbb1c38a9173bfb1a2),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.5 x86_64)
[10:39:40] E/launcher - WebDriverError: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506106 (8a06c39c4582fbfbab6966dbb1c38a9173bfb1a2),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.5 x86_64)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/Users/viddrawings/simaxx_portal_repo/simaxx-front-end/src/main/webapp/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:505:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/Users/viddrawings/simaxx_portal_repo/simaxx-front-end/src/main/webapp/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (/Users/viddrawings/simaxx_portal_repo/simaxx-front-end/src/main/webapp/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:440:13)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:169:7)
```

Protractor config:

```
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  beforeLaunch: function() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
  }
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  }
};
```

Comment: is chrome installed ?

Comment: Yes, Chrome is installed, I work on Mac though.

Comment: Have you made changes to the protractor config? If so, please share your config. Also, how did you reinstall the drivers? Did you use `webdriver-manager clean` then `webdriver-manager update`?

Comment: I will add my config here. I did use the commands that you are suggesting, but it simply didn't work for some reason. The commands get executed but it doesn't resolve my problem :(

Comment: Is chrome installed in the default location or a custom one? Looks like it can't find it in the default install location.Also, you need to make sure the path to the binary chrome is included in `etc/paths`.

Comment: @tehbeardedone default location, that is why I don't understand. On Windows it seems to work fine however. Mac somehow is the problem. I will check if the path is set in etc/paths

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a script

`/usr/local/bin/chrome`

```
cd '/Applications/Google Chrome 3.app/Contents/MacOS/'
./'Google Chrome'
```